# Open Widget Configure from home screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I have an activity `PlaceSearch.java` which also happens to be the Configure class of my Widget. I am developing a weather widget so i am using `FrameLayout` which consist of an `ImageButton` and then `LinearLayout`. [Please see this link](http://pastie.org/private/6xtrehtzzyrphm1gs0usbg).

I want to open `PlaceSearch.java` when a user clicks on the `widget` on the `home screen`. So I have used the following code for implementing it

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    System.out.println("entering onUpdate");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, TimeService.class));
    for(int id: appWidgetIds){
        System.out.println(id);
    RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,Preferences.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pi =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ibmainBackground, pi);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, view);
    }
}
```

But this is not working perhaps due to the fact that `FrameLayout` causes `LinearLayout` to overlap on `ImageButton` thus the `ImageButton` is never actually clicked. If so, provide me a correct way to open the activity.

Comment: Try `getActivity()` instead of `getBroadcast()`

Comment: @shoerat such a silly mistake... I scratched my head for hours on this.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me had to write `PendingIntent.getActivity(....)`. Working fine now thanks to @shoe rat . For others who are also trying to open activities from home screen, add the `PendingIntent` to the base Layout. for eg- for me it is `mainLayout`.